# Gremlin simplePath() not working in a loop

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I'm trying to write a DAG traversal accounting for the possibility that the there actually might be cycles (bad data, etc.). So on the [toy graph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Basic-Graph-Traversals):

```
gg = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()  
gg.v(2).addEdge('knows', gg.v(4))
gg.v(4).addEdge('knows', gg.v(3))
```

I do this:

```
gg.v(1).as('x').out('knows').loop('x'){it.object.out('knows').hasNext()}{true}
```

And get expected result:

```
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
```

Now I add a cycle:

```
gg.v(3).addEdge('knows', gg.v(1))
```

So to have it enumerate all found vertices without looping forever, I do this:

```
gg.v(1).as('x').out('knows').simplePath.loop('x'}{it.object.out('knows').simplePath.hasNext()}{true}[0..10].path
```

And I get this:

```
==>[v[1], v[2]]
==>[v[1], v[4]]
==>[v[1], v[2], v[4]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3]]
==>[v[1], v[2], v[4], v[3]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3], v[1]]
==>[v[1], v[2], v[4], v[3], v[1]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3], v[1], v[2]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3], v[1], v[4]]
==>[v[1], v[2], v[4], v[3], v[1], v[2]]
==>[v[1], v[2], v[4], v[3], v[1], v[4]]
```

So cycles were not eliminated, and simplePath() did nothing, it allowed the loop to continue even though there was a cycle. Note that if loop is not in the picture, it works fine:

```
gg.v(1).out('knows').out('knows').out('knows').out('knows').out('knows').simplePath.path
```

This produces empty result. So my question is - what's wrong here? Why cycles are not eliminated and how I do traversal without cycles if simplePath does not work? I could probably try to keep track of visited vertices manually with side effects, but I would expect Gremlin do the traversal for me... So what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's what you're looking for:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).as("x").dedup().out("knows").loop("x") { it.object.out("knows").hasNext() } { true }.path()
==>[v[1], v[2]]
==>[v[1], v[4]]
==>[v[1], v[2], v[4]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3], v[1]]
gremlin>
```

Comment: That seems to be working, though I'm not sure I understand why. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielKuppitz, why does the last output path have a cycle in it? It returns back to ```v[1]```.

Comment: `dedup()` in a loop behaves like a global `simplePath()`, but it only takes the loop-traversal into account, not the first vertex. You can get rid of the last line by adding a `simplePath()` after the loop, but I guess the result that I've shown was the one Stas was looking for.